# Light casts wird shadow on glass!

Tags: shadows, glass

[image]

When I try to make the glass cover for my clock, this is what happens. The strange ball appears to be a shadow that is cast by the light source. When I tick off specular for the light source, the shadow is gone, but the glass is no longer visible. Please help, I'm a beginner and I'm at my wit's end!

Comment: Does it actually render like that? It looks more like a transparent hole that shows the grid floor behind it, or is it reflecting the grid floor? You might need to [share your blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/630/935) for someone to find what is happening.

Comment: I made the glass all over again and it seems to render ok now. I do not know what was happening before. Thank you for your reply though! It was a project for school, so I'll just wait and see if it got accepted :)